# Helper class for sql server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, helper

When is it appropriate to create a helper class for a sql server database using the asp.net framework? Basically I'm trying to create a minature wiki (with multiple pages) and storing all of the data/strings for a specific page into a table on it's own.

Comment: Whenever one would be useful. :-P Seriously, you're going to need to elaborate on this to make it a valid SO question. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior see above edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always and Never.

Always, because you want good separation of your data tier from your business logic and presentation tiers (or model and view, or whatever framework you use).  Make sure you're thinking of it in these terms, too.

Never, because this is already done for you, on several levels.  There are numerous ORMs out there, including Linq-to-sql, NHibernate, Entity Framework, and more.  More than that, what is ADO.Net but a set of classes to encapsulate your server?

Answer (score 1):

Well it could be appropriate to return a single instance of a DbConnection object - that way you only specify how to connect to the DB in one spot.

You may find it useful to have a base class for your ADO layer which provides these generic methods to deal with the ADO (part of the .NET framework for connecting to SQL server).

You could have a helper method to populate an object from a DataReader using reflection too.

Also for putting parameters together to send to a SQL command or Stored procedure.

Hope you find this helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's heavily dependant on your project.

For code clarity, and your own sanity, you might find it easier to make a wrapper class for all of your Database manipulation. This way you can have the rest of your code work with native objects, rather than the contents of a DataReader.

Just my advice, but hopefully helpful.